# Best way to convert Hex string file to integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, binaryfiles

I have 10GB of data in binary files with little endian format and I am converting them to integer like:

```
with open(myfile, 'rb') as inh:
    data = inh.read()

for i in range(0, len(data), 4):
    pos = struct.unpack('i', data[i:i+4])
```

But it takes really long time to convert each file with 100MB of data. Is there any way to speed the process up?

Comment: maybe a mmap would be faster reading 4 bytes at a time

Comment: Do the files contain hex strings like 'FFFF' or binary numbers like 0xFFFF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using numpy, you can use [`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.memmap('foo.bin', dtype='<i4', mode='r')
```

For example,

```
In [122]: !hexdump foo.bin
0000000 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00
0000010 00 01 00 00 01 01 00 00 ff ff ff ff fe ff ff ff
0000020

In [123]: data = np.memmap('foo.bin', dtype='<i4', mode='r')

In [124]: data
Out[124]: memmap([  1,   2,   3, 255, 256, 257,  -1,  -2], dtype=int32)

In [125]: data[6]
Out[125]: -1
```

It might not be necessary to memory-map the data, in which case you can simply read it into an array with [`numpy.fromfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html).  For example,

```
In [129]: data = np.fromfile('foo.bin', dtype='<i4')

In [130]: data
Out[130]: array([  1,   2,   3, 255, 256, 257,  -1,  -2], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get binary string instead of integer like `100101001000000111010010101011`? We are counting the photons and I have to split the binary string into two [ 0 to 28 bits is for order of counts ,29-32bits is for counter.

Comment: For each integer `a` you could try something like `order = a & (2**29-1)` and `counter = a >> 29`.  For further discussion, ask a new question (but try searching for similar questions first).

Answer (score 4):

`numpy` is likely faster, but you can also allow `struct.unpack` to do the looping instead of Python:

```
L = struct.unpack('{}i'.format(len(data)//4),data)
```

The result is the entire list of integers unpacked.

It took a few seconds to do a 400MB data blob.  Here's a shorter example:

```
>>> L=list(range(20))
>>> struct.pack('20i',*L)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00'
>>> b = struct.pack('20i',*L)
>>> struct.unpack('20i',b)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Padraic Cunningham's suggestion, using memory-mapped files:

```
import mmap
import contextlib

with open(myfile, 'rb') as inh:
    with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(inh.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as m:
        for i in range(0, len(m), 4):
            pos = struct.unpack('i', m[i:i+4])
```

Please read [here](https://pymotw.com/2/mmap/) for more info on the `mmap` module in the standard library

Comment: You'll lose any gains in the Python `for` loop.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes, I am aware it may not be the best solution. My answer is to show how it can be done with memory-mapped files, since it is quite close to the code in the question, which reads the whole lot in memory